# Laravel retrieve param in class constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Here is my route:

```
Route::controller('/app/{companyId}/', 'HomeController', array('before' => 'auth'));
```

How can I retrieve $companyId argument in __constructor to avoid retrieving it separate in all my actions?

Comment: You shouldn't have to retrieve it in the action, I'm pretty sure it should be passed in as a parameter. See http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as a duplicate. The OP is asking specifically how to get the variable in the *constructor*, not simply how to pass it to a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the parameters in the __construct of your controller you could do this:

```
class HomeController extends \BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->routeParamters = Route::current()->parameters();
    }
}
```

it will return a key value list of parameters for the route (ex: `['companyId' => '1']`) [@see \Illuminate\Routing\Route](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L319)

You can also get a specific parameter using the [getParameter()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L268) or [parameter()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L280) methods.

**NOTE:** I'm not sure this is such a great idea tho. There might be a more elegant way to solve or better approach to your problem.

Comment: I think this is indeed the only way to go. I would not recommand parsing the route parameters from inside the controller though : it is the router's responsability to parse the url and then pass the parameters to the controller.

Comment: @arthurfl Agreed, I'm not sure this is such a great idea. But if you must that's how :). I'll amend my answer with a warning.

Comment: I would think `Route::resource` would be the best tool for this job.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the process simpler, route model binding seems to be the easiest way to go. Instead of having to fetch for the right Model instance in every action of your controller, you pass the right Model to your controller during the routing process.

But you have to use Route::resource. In routes.php :

```
Route::bind('company', 'Company');
Route::resource('company', 'HomeController');
```

Then you have an instance of category passed to your controller. For example for /company/1 :

```
public function show($company)
{
    // Here you can use, for instance, $company->name
}
```